# Querying Twilio calls list resource doesn't paginate the results using Ruby or PHP

Tags: ruby, twilio, twilio-api

According to Twilio's documentation [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/call#paging) regarding "paging":

> The list returned to you includes paging information. If you plan on requesting more records than will fit on a single page, you may want to use the provided nextpageuri rather than incrementing through the pages by page number.

It then gives an example:

```
# Initialize Twilio Client
@client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(account_sid, auth_token)

@client.calls.list
       .each do |call|
         puts call.direction
       end
```

However, doing this just returns an array of all calls, there isn't any paging information or limiting of results or any "pages".

For my purposes I'm actually filtering the query like this:

```
@calls = @client.calls.list(
          start_time_after: @time
          start_time_before: @another_time
)
```

Because my date filter range is a 1 month period and there are currently about 4.5k calls to retrieve, its taking quite a while to process (and sometimes it just never processes)

I'm using the twilio helper library ruby gem "twilio-ruby" and running ruby 2.5
I've also tried using PHP with the respective twilio helper library and have found the same result.

Using curl however does work and gives paging information, its also incredibly fast compared to using the helper libraries

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

`list` will paginate through, loading all the resources it can.

There are other calls that will stream the API in a lazier fashion, if that is more useful for your use case. For example, you can use `each` and it will load the calls lazily until they have run out.

```
@calls = @client.calls.each(
  start_time_after: @time
  start_time_before: @another_time
) do |call|
  puts call.direction
end
```

If you do want to manually paginate yourself, you can the `page` method to get a `CallPage` object and iterate from there.

```
page = @client.calls.page(
  start_time_after: @time
  start_time_before: @another_time
)
while !page.nil? do
  page.each { |call| puts call.direction }
  page = page.next_page
end
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Are you saying that to get a paginated result set I need to use the `page` method?

If I call the `list` method I will just receive a full result set (like the 4.5k results I am currently getting)?

I just thought that the documentation stated that list resources would contain `Paging Information` which would contain properties like `first_page_uri` and `next_page_uri` which I'm currently not getting. 

I am however getting that result when I use `curl` on the same endpoint??

Comment: The documentation also states  –

"When fetching multiple pages of API results, use the provided nextpageuri parameter to retrieve the next page of results. All of 
the Twilio Helper Libraries use the nextpageuri to page through 
resources."

[Paging Through API Resources](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/response#response-formats-list-filters)

Comment: Yes, using `page` gets you a page and uses the `nextpageurl` parameter when you then call `next_page`. The `list` method uses `page` internally and paginates through for you. You can set a `:limit` option on `list` to retrieve less results, but if you want to page manually, then `page` is the method for you. I apologise for the discrepancy between the method names and the documentation that causes this confusion though.